What to look for in Android Profiler to understand performance issues?
In my app, I navigate from the main page to Google Maps and display markers on the map. App's CPU utilization shoots up to 90%, and my memory reaches 300 from 180.
I took this memory heap dump, what should I look for to know what is causing such high resource utilization?
Here are the screenshots of the dump-



When Showing all classes-





Memory heap dump can show the memory allocated to objects in the JVM heap, including native memory if they are referenced by JVM objects. To understand your app's memory consumption, a good start point may be Android Studio Profiler's "View Live Telemetry" task which can tell what kinds of memory usage have increased. Here is a screenshot as an example.
If it's Java memory, a heap dump is appropriate. If it's native memory, you can try the "Track Memory Consumption - Native Allocations" task.
